# Stop rundeck workflow in a specific step

Tags: rundeck

Is there a way to stop a workflow on a specific step?

For example, if I have a 5 steps workflow, how can I stop workflow (with succeed status) on step 2 (without executing steps 3,4 and 5) ?

Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Flow Control plugin](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/flow-control-plugin) as a step: in your job you can [add](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rundeck-plugins/flow-control-plugin/master/doc-select.png) a new Workflow step between your steps named "Flow Control" to stop the job on any [step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HISj8.jpg).

I leave a Job Definition example:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>c84e6ac0-3bb1-4021-9924-0603cf9ddc22</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>JobEXAMPLE</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <exec>echo "step one"</exec>
      </command>
      <command>
        <exec>echo "step two"</exec>
      </command>
      <command>
        <step-plugin type='flow-control'>
          <configuration>
            <entry key='fail' value='false' />
            <entry key='halt' value='true' />
          </configuration>
        </step-plugin>
      </command>
      <command>
        <exec>echo "step three"</exec>
      </command>
      <command>
        <exec>echo "step four"</exec>
      </command>
      <command>
        <exec>echo "step five"</exec>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>c84e6ac0-3bb1-4021-9924-0603cf9ddc22</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

And [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFbDV.jpg) the result.

Alternatively, you can play a bit with Rundeck (basically "scripting") on my following example, I have used a file content like a flag, that value is evaluated on each step  (which changes intentionally on the third step):

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>8f31dee3-255b-4adb-a884-9cd3cce39a65</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>JobEXAMPLE</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='sequential'>
      <command>
        <exec>echo "1" &gt; file</exec>
      </command>
      <command>
        <fileExtension>.sh</fileExtension>
        <script><![CDATA[value=$(cat file)

if [ $value = 1 ]; then
   echo "i am the first step..."
fi]]></script>
        <scriptargs />
        <scriptinterpreter>/bin/bash</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
      <command>
        <fileExtension>.sh</fileExtension>
        <script><![CDATA[value=$(cat file)

if [ $value = 1 ]; then
   echo "i am the second step..."
fi]]></script>
        <scriptargs />
        <scriptinterpreter>/bin/bash</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
      <command>
        <fileExtension>.sh</fileExtension>
        <script><![CDATA[# intentional change to file
echo "0" > file


value=$(cat file)

if [ $value = 1 ]; then
   echo "i am the third step..."
fi]]></script>
        <scriptargs />
        <scriptinterpreter>/bin/bash</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
      <command>
        <fileExtension>.sh</fileExtension>
        <script><![CDATA[value=$(cat file)

if [ $value = 1 ]; then
   echo "i am the fourth step..."
fi]]></script>
        <scriptargs />
        <scriptinterpreter>/bin/bash</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
      <command>
        <fileExtension>.sh</fileExtension>
        <script><![CDATA[value=$(cat file)

if [ $value = 1 ]; then
   echo "i am the fifth step..."
fi]]></script>
        <scriptargs />
        <scriptinterpreter>/bin/bash</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
      <command>
        <exec>echo "done!"</exec>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>8f31dee3-255b-4adb-a884-9cd3cce39a65</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

Check the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wntyS.jpg).

Comment: Thanks for your response @MegaDrive68K. Please, Can you direct me to a  Flow Control plugin example ?. I'm trying it, but I cannot understand how it work and how to use it. Thnanks in advance :-)